# ¿Que le falta a mi código python con OpenGL ES?

Tags: python, opengl

Estaba viendo en la wikipedia que WebGl 1.0 esta basado en OpenGL ES 2.0, entonces se me ocurrió averiguar que pasaba si usaba las mismas instrucciones de Javascript en Python, por lo que genere el siguiente código, el problema es que funciona en ocasiones, al ejecutar el código aveces dibuja y otras no, cuando creo que ya funciona con la nueva instrucción que le agregue, hago una modificación sencilla, como cambiar el color, ejecuto el programa y de nuevo, aveces dibuja y otras ocasiones no lo hace, en la terminal no aparece nada.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import glfw
from OpenGL.GLES2 import *
import numpy


def initialize():
    #Iniciamos GLFW.
    glfw.init()
    #Creamos una ventana.
    ventana = glfw.create_window(684, 384, "Titulo", None, None)
    #Estableceremos en que ventana dibujaremos.
    glfw.make_context_current(ventana)
    
    
    vertice_codigo = """
attribute vec4 coordinates;
uniform vec4 translation;
void main(void) {
    gl_Position = coordinates + translation;
}
    """
    
    vertice_sombra = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER)
    glShaderSource(vertice_sombra, vertice_codigo)
    glCompileShader(vertice_sombra)
    
    cara_codigo = """
void main(void) {
    gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
}
    """
    
    cara_sombra = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER)
    glShaderSource(cara_sombra, cara_codigo)
    glCompileShader(cara_sombra)
    
    sombra = glCreateProgram()
    glAttachShader(sombra, vertice_sombra)
    glAttachShader(sombra, cara_sombra)
    glLinkProgram(sombra)
    glUseProgram(sombra)
    
    coordenadas = glGetAttribLocation(sombra, "coordinates")
    glVertexAttribPointer(coordenadas, 3, GL_FLOAT, False, 0, 0)
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(coordenadas)
    
    traslacion = glGetUniformLocation(sombra, "translation")
    glUniform4f(traslacion, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
    
    vertice = [-0.5,0.5,0.0,-0.5,-0.5,0.0,0.5,-0.5,0.0]
    vertice = numpy.array(vertice, dtype=numpy.float32)
    
    vertice_bufer = glGenBuffers(1)
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertice_bufer)
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 48, vertice, GL_STATIC_DRAW)
    
    while not glfw.window_should_close(ventana):
        glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)
        glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.3, 0.0)
        glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL)
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
        
        glViewport(0, 0, 685, 384)
        
        
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertice_bufer)
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3)
        
        glfw.swap_buffers(ventana)
        glfw.poll_events()

    glfw.terminate()

initialize()
```